Borders of Paran?
The child Ishmael lived in the wilderness of Paran (פָּארָן):
Genesis 21:21: "God was with the boy and he grew up; he dwelt in the wilderness and became skilled with a bow.
He lived in the wilderness of Paran; and his mother got a wife for him from the land of Egypt."
The sons of Ishmael dwelt from Havilah to Asshur (the whole of Arabia?).
Genesis 25:18: "their names, in the order of their birth: Nebaioth, the first-born of Ishmael, Kedar, Adbeel, Mibsam, Mishma, Dumah, Massa, Hadad, Tema, Jetur, Naphish, and Kedmah. These were the years of the life of Ishmael: one hundred and thirty-seven years; then he breathed his last and died, and was gathered to his kin. They dwelt from Havilah, by Shur, which is close to Egypt, all the way to Asshur; they camped alongside all their kin.
Should the borders of the wilderness of Paran, where the child Ishmael lived, include all the land from Havilah to Asshur? If not, why not?

The wilderness of Paran was in the south-west of Eretz Israel (Sinai Peninsula) or South of Israel (in the west of the Arabian Peninsula). It was one of the places of travels of Jewish people during their 40 years travels in the desert. The land of Ashur is to the East of Syria or in the North-East of Eretz Israel. The simple reading of the area of dwelling of Ishmaelites should include Eretz Israel. In the ancient world the road from Egypt or Western Arabia to Mesopotamia was going through Eretz Israel or lands of Edom, Moav and Ammon.  King Yoshiyahu unsuccessfully tried to prevent pharaoh Neco from going to fight with the Assyrian army on the river Euphrates (Melakhim B 23:29). Neither Eretz Israel, Ammon, Moav, Edom, Midian, or Syria were inheritance of Ishmael. We must conclude that Ishmael's descendands were nomadic people originating in the wilderness of Paran and moving with their cattle on unsettled lands along the Southern or Eastern borders of countries of Levant.

@Y DJ. What I understand from your answer, is that we shouldn't call the land where Ishmael's descendands  dwelt (from Havilah to Asshur) Paran . as the Paran, where the child Ishmael lived, is much smaller . right?

@Capri1capri Yes. Paran is one of the places where Jewish people stayed during their 40 years of travels in the desert. It could include a desert in the Sinai peninsula or areas of Arabian Peninsula south of Eilat (depending on how one defines the desert route of the Jewish people). I edited the answer a bit to reflect this point.

"should" is the wrong verb. There is no language of the specific land of Paran being given to Ishmael in the sense that Eretz Yisroel and Mt. Seir were given to the Jews and the Edomites.
